# VMware Tools does not resize the display on latest VMware Player

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-player, vmware-tools

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 on VMware Workstation 12 Player. For some type of unknown reason, when I installed VMware Tools, it asked me if I wanted to install "this legacy version". Has VMware stopped updating VMware Tools for Linux? The version of VMware Tools I used is 10.0.5.

Anyway, after installing it and rebooting, maximizing the window does resize the guest's display? Why? What can I do to fix it?